# Raw binary floats in CSV and JSON - does such a standard exist?

Tags: json, csv, floating-point

CSV and JSON are great because they're simple specs that are easy to write a parser for. (I ask this question for both CSV and JSON, because I assume there'd not be enough distinction to justify two separate questions.)

A tradeoff of the simpicity in these formats is that integers and floating point numbers especially take more space than needed. E.g. "3.141592653589" is 14 bytes! This takes extra space and can cost precision.

Storing an ASCII representation of the float might work, but makes me feel uneasy, because any byte could be, say, a comma or a quote mark, breaking a parser.

I'm curious if there's any agreed upon extensions to JSON and CSV that addresses this issue.

Comment: C has a `%a` format for the `printf` and `scanf` family, which uses a hexadecimal floating-point representation.  Still only four bits per byte, but at least it encodes the internal binary floating-point values accurately, without a potentially lossy conversion to/from decimal.

Comment: this doesn't sound like anything I've head of, maybe you could explain why you're thinking about this rather than just using a pure text or binary format?  note that sticking with standard formats means you get to use [high performance parsers](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson)

Comment: Thank you SteveSummit -- I hadn't thought of that but that's smart! It gets 80% of the way there for very little extra effort. And hi Sam Mason. This was mostly curiosity. I assumed such a format would already exist (perhaps during the times when these performance gains were necessary) but I couldn't find one! As you show, it's good to stick with existing formats.